# How to init collectionView after loading custom function

Tags: ios, swift, function, asynchronous, viewcontroller

I have a problem with `func collectionView` inside in `class MoviesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {`

This function init automatically, and I don't want to start automatically. Or to do so when it has finished loading a function that load external data.

This is my structure code of `ViewController.swift`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet var collectionView1 : UICollectionView!
```

This is function i want load before `CollectionView`

```
func loaddata(){
  let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite/testdata.php")!
  let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
  let bodyData = "data=something"
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

  request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
  (response, data, error) in
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!               
  }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  loaddata()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1920, 2200)
}
```

And here, func `CollectionView` init automatically

```
//this is function that load automatically
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
  insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
  return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 50.0)
}

// this is function load automatically
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  if (collectionView == self.collectionView1) {
    let cell : FeaturedCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifierFeatured, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeaturedCollectionViewCell
    let  imageFilename = "featured-\(indexPath.row).jpg"
    cell.featuredImage.image = UIImage(named: imageFilename)
    return cell
  }
  return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

How I can do to keep `ViewController` start before `loadData`? Or to `ViewController` not start until you call the function from `loadData`

Comment: why are you having scrollview & collection view both in a same view ?

Comment: It is a structure that I get from here. It works well, but I need to change it. CollectionView is in a ScrollView. That's why starts automatically?

Comment: you can reload the collection view after the `loadData()` function completes fetching the network data. another thing i didn't find the implementation of `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` which tells the collection view how many item will be rendered, it should return `0` initiailly when u have no data.

Comment: does implementing the `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` in your data soruce & returning `0` from it (when no data available) stop calling the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't care about collection view loading items when you don't have the items yet. The worst case that can happen is that nothing is displayed.

However, when your data finishes loading, you should call `collectionView.reloadData` to display the data you have just finished loading from the server.

If you don't want the collection view to be displayed at all when the data is still being loaded, simply set `collectionView.hidden = true` and then`collectionView.hidden = false` in your completion handler. You should probably also display an activity indicator (e.g. `UIActivityIndicator` instance) to inform the user that data is still being loaded.

Also I would advise not to load data from `viewDidLoad`. You should rather use `viewDidAppear`.